# Turn off "This is the Primary Sidebar Widget Area" message

Tags: widgets, genesis-theme-framework

I have dozens of sub-sites with varying sidebars (some custom, some use primary, some blank).

For those logged into WordPress, is there a hook to disable the  following message from blank sidebars?

> This is the Primary Sidebar Widget Area. You can add content to this
>   area by visiting your Widgets Panel and adding new widgets to this
>   area.

It does not appear when logged out, but I'd prefer it not be there for editors either as it can be confusing. I know that I can add empty widgets there to get rid of it, but there has to be a better way.

We're using WordPress 4.9.4, Genesis 2.5.3 + custom child theme.

Answer (score 2):

This code handles the sidebar:

```
add_action( 'genesis_sidebar', 'genesis_do_sidebar' );
/**
 * Echo primary sidebar default content.
 *
 * Only shows if sidebar is empty, and current user has the ability to edit theme options (manage widgets).
 *
 * @since 1.2.0
 */
function genesis_do_sidebar() {

    if ( ! dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar' ) && current_user_can( 'edit_theme_options' )  ) {
        genesis_default_widget_area_content( __( 'Primary Sidebar Widget Area', 'genesis' ) );
    }

}
```

You can unhook `genesis_do_sidebar` from `genesis_sidebar`, then wire up your own sidebar function to prevent the default content from being output:

```
remove_action( 'genesis_sidebar', 'genesis_do_sidebar' );
add_action( 'genesis_sidebar', 'wpse_genesis_do_sidebar' );
/**
 * Outputs widgets for sidebar without default content.
 */
function wpse_genesis_do_sidebar() {
    dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar' );
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Dave. This appears to work, but it also removes other custom sidebars.